# How can I create and use session in app context with Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create global session with Flask-SQLAlchemy before request and handle it after request.

First I have some app factory

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    if "FLASK_CONFIG" in os.environ:
        app.config.from_envvar("FLASK_CONFIG")

    db.init_app(app)

    return app
```

I don't truly understand, what does db.init_app do. I know it initializes the DB, but what does it exactly mean? How can I use it within the applicaction?

So I did the ugly thing after creating the application:

```
from flask import g
from app_factory import *

app = create_app()

@app.before_request
def createSession():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def closeSession():
    db = g.pop('db', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()
```

In this case, I don't understand, why db.init_app is needed, because I probably don't use it that way. I can see in app object, there are is extension incl. sqlalchemy, where db object is stored, but I cannot access it some easy way.

When I insert records to DB, I just use

```
g.db.session.add(whatever_db_object)
```

over and over in different modules and when request ends well (200), I use

```
g.db.session.commit()
```

It works, but I have feeling this is not the way to go. Could you please give me some advice about some best practices in this topic?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Flask-SQLA already ties the session's lifetime to that of a request, and `db.session` is actually a scoped session registry, so instead of using `g` all over you would just import `db` and use `db.session` all over.

Comment: Wow, I tried that before, but I had to miss something, thanks. Is that because of `db.init_app(app)` or it has entirely different purpose?

Comment: Looking at [its documentation](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy.init_app) I'd say running `db.init_app(app)` handles (among other things) registering the teardown etc. handlers as you've done.